# MSBuild copy task and condition name from file with wildcards

Tags: msbuild

I have a FilesToExclude2.txt file which contains all excludes like this :

```
*.settings
*#*
*.vbproj*
*.csproj*
*\Errors\*
*\Errors
*\_vti_*\*
*\_vti_*
*\CVS\*
```

In my tasks file, there is a copy task

```
  <Target Name="CustomModuleCopy">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ModuleFiles Include="$(SolutionModuleName)\$(ProjectModuleName)\**\*.*" />
      <FileToExclude Include="$(BasePath)\$(SolutionModuleName)\FilesToExclude2.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(FileToExclude)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileContents" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ModuleFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(ModuleFiles->'$(DestFolder)\$(ProjectModuleName)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" Condition="'%(ModuleFiles.Identity)' != @(FileContents)" ContinueOnError="false" />

    <!--CallTarget Targets="RemoveCustomModuleConfigFiles" /-->
  </Target>
```

Without the "condition" attribute on the copy task, everything's works fine, but I do not know how to implement the condition with wildcard and if it is possible

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated :) this is freaking me out for few hours...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would it not be easier to just use the exclude property instead?
as in 
Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ModuleFiles Include="c:\code\**\*.*"
               Exclude="@(FileContents)" />
</ItemGroup>


<!--<Copy SourceFiles="@(ModuleFiles)" DestinationFolder="Some|Destination" Condition="'%(ModuleFiles.Identity)' != @(FileContents)" ContinueOnError="false" />

CallTarget Targets="RemoveCustomModuleConfigFiles" /-->
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it seems the "exclude" property do not take the wildcards as specials characters...

Comment: I had the realine bit in my answer but it never made the ctrl+V... All fixed now?

Comment: no am sorry, I tried your solution but the files are not excluded as you can see in the result below/above... (in another answer posted by me because the comment is 500 chars max...)

Comment: the exclude attribute with "**\\*.config;**\\*.csproj" remove files, but if I create a txt file contains **\\*.config and **\\*.csproj

the files are copied to the destination...

Answer (score 0):

the following code

```
<Target Name="CustomModuleCopy">
  <ItemGroup>
      <FileToExclude Include="$(BasePath)\$(SolutionModuleName)\FilesToExclude.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(FileToExclude)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileContents" />
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ModuleFiles Include="$(SolutionModuleName)\$(ProjectModuleName)\**\*.*" Exclude="@(FileContents)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ModuleFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(ModuleFiles->'$(DestFolder)\$(ProjectModuleName)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" ContinueOnError="false" />
  <Message Text="Exclude = @(FileContents)" />
  <!--CallTarget Targets="RemoveCustomModuleConfigFiles" /-->
</Target>
```

produce this output in console :

```
copy /y "CPBMessaging\CPBMessagingWeb_NotificationMessage\Web.Debug.config" "C:\__CPB\CPBSite\CPBMessagingWeb_NotificationMessage\Web.Debug.config"
Copying file from "CPBMessaging\CPBMessagingWeb_NotificationMessage\Web.Release.config" to "C:\__CPB\CPBSite\CPBMessagingWeb_NotificationMessage\Web.Release.config"
copy /y "CPBMessaging\CPBMessagingWeb_NotificationMessage\Web.Release.config" "C:\__CPB\CPBSite\CPBMessagingWeb_NotificationMessage\Web.Release.config"
Exclude = *.cab;*.config;*.vb;*.cs;*.resx;*.xsx;*.bak;*.myapp;*.settings;*#*;
*.vbproj*;*.csproj*;*\Errors\*;*\Errors;*\_vti_*\*;*\_vti_*;*\CVS\*;*\CVS;
```